# Set border for 1st line in uitextview

Tags: ios, uitextview, border

How to set border for 1st line only in uitextview.

If it's possible let me know as some examples

If you put -1 vote please tell me the reason

Comment: What do you mean by border for the first line only?

Comment: it not posible in textview

Comment: @maddy- border of what...?

Comment: @woz i mean They are multiple line in UITextView but i want set border for 1st line only

Comment: A border or an underline?

Comment: @vivek sehrawat set border color and width

Comment: Border color and width are the property of UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

UITextView has no property to set the border of text. You can set text font to Bold,Italic and  Underline through Attributed String.

Here is the Reference link : [NSAttributedString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)